# Download a repository in Github along with composer packages

Tags: php, git, github, composer-php

Without using Composer, is it possible to download a repository in Github along with it's defined composer packages?

For example: [FluxBB 2](https://github.com/fluxbb/fluxbb2) requires Laravel 4.

I was hoping to download FluxBB and at the same time the packages of Laravel 4 without using Composer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually projects that use composer will ignore 3rd party components. In .gitignore you will see /vendor. This is the place where Composer downloads its dependencies.

> This will find the latest version of monolog/monolog that matches the supplied version constraint and download it into the vendor directory. It's a convention to put third party code into a directory named vendor. In case of monolog it will put it into vendor/monolog/monolog.
>
> **Tip: If you are using git for your project, you probably want to add vendor into your .gitignore. You really don't want to add all of that code to your repository.**
> http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-dependencies

Doing it manually is a bit of a hassle. Composer uses [packagist](https://packagist.org/) to get its files (if you look at a package it has a source added to it Laravel https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/framework).

Composer auto loads the needed files automatically so its a big time saver.

> For libraries that specify autoload information, Composer generates a vendor/autoload.php file. You can simply include this file and you will get autoloading for free.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

> This makes it really easy to use third party code. For example: If
> your project depends on monolog, you can just start using classes from
> it, and they will be autoloaded.
> http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: Is there any way to this using Github's UI without using composer?

Comment: you can look at the composer.json and see what version of laravel it needs. In this case "laravel/framework": "4.0.*" meaning you will download from laravel's github the branch or version that is 4.0.<anything> Hope I helped you.

Comment: Main problem with this manual copy is that, in my example, laravel too needs packages to work. Endless manual download that is. Thanks though.

Comment: This is the beauty of composer and why its so used. It handles the dependencies for you, saving you hours of manual download and configuration.

Comment: If you once got Composer installed, you will never ever work without it. There is no reason not to use it, unless there are obstacles that prevent it in unusual cases. What's your reason?